# NHibernate: Or-clause with Components

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have two classes:

```
public class Person{

  public virtual string Name { get; set;}
  public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address{
  public virtual string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want NHibernate to give me all Persons where Name is equal to "Xyz" or Address.Street is equal to "Xyz".

This approach is an and-conjunction:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person));
criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("Name", "Xyz"))
.CreateCriteria("Address").Add(Expression.Eq("Street", "Xyz"));
```

What I want is and or-clause.

Thank you very much!
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I've always just used HQL queries for this - much easier to write *and* read (at least if you're used to SQL. It's something like this:

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM Person p WHERE p.Name = :Name OR p.Address.Street = :Street");
query.SetParameter("Name", "Xyz");
query.SetParameter("Street", "Xyz");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. You're right, these HQL queries are much easier :-)